# No se muestran los datos introducidos

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase Garito en la cual tengo implementada una serie de setters y getters para poder interactuar con su contenido. Aparte tengo unas funciones que acceden a esos métodos para poder mostrar los datos. He conseguido que se muestren haciendo uso de **constructores parametrizados** pero no consigo que funcionen usando un **constructor por defecto**.

Este es mi código:

**Garito.cpp**

```
include "Garito.h"

Garito::Garito(){        
}      

Garito::Garito(std::string nombre,std::string direccion)
        : nombre(nombre),
        direccion(direccion){

}

Garito::Garito(const Garito &orig)
        : nombre(orig.nombre),
        direccion(orig.direccion){

}

Garito::~Garito(){

}

void Garito::setNombre(std::string nombre){
    if (nombre == "")
        throw std::string ("[setNombre]: No se ha introducido ningun texto"); 
}
std::string Garito::getNombre() const{
    return nombre;
}

void Garito::setDireccion(std::string direccion){
    if (direccion == "")
        throw std::string ("[setDireccion]: No se ha introducido ningun texto");
}

std::string Garito::getDireccion() const{
    return direccion;
}
```

**Funciones.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funciones.h"


void funciones::mostrarTemazo(const Temazo& t){

   std::cout <<"Interprete: "<<t.getInterprete()<<std::endl;
   std::cout <<"Titulo: "<<t.getTitulo()<<std::endl;
   std::cout <<"Duracion: "<<t.getDuracion()<<" segundos"<<std::endl;
   std::cout <<"Puntaucion: "<<t.getPuntuacion()<< " puntos"<<std::endl;  

}

void funciones::mostrarGarito(const Garito& g){
   std::cout <<"Nombre del Garito: "<<g.getNombre()<<std::endl; 
   std::cout <<"Direccion del Garito: "<<g.getDireccion()<<std::endl;

}

void funciones::mostrarFecha(const Fecha& f){
    std::cout <<"Dia: "<<f.getDia()<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Mes: "<<f.getMes()<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Anio: "<<f.getAnio()<<std::endl;

}

void funciones::pideGarito(Garito& gg){
    std::string ngarito;

    std::cout <<"Introduce los datos del garito"<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"Introduce el nombre del garito"<<std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, ngarito);
    gg.setNombre(ngarito);
    std::cout <<"Introduce la direccion del garito"<<std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, ngarito);
    gg.setDireccion(ngarito);

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Temazo.h"
#include "Garito.h"
#include "Fecha.h"
#include "funciones.h"


/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Garito g;
    funciones::pideGarito(g);
    funciones::mostrarGarito(g);

}
```

El programa tal cual compila, puedo introducir los datos pero a la hora de mostrarlos me muestra un espacio en blanco.

Answer (score 2):

> El programa tal cual compila, puedo introducir los datos pero a la hora de mostrarlos me muestra un espacio en blanco.

Es normal que te pase, porque no guardas los datos:

```
void Garito::setNombre(std::string nombre){
    if (nombre == "")
        throw std::string ("[setNombre]: No se ha introducido ningun texto"); 
}

void Garito::setDireccion(std::string direccion){
    if (direccion == "")
        throw std::string ("[setDireccion]: No se ha introducido ningun texto");
}
```

¿Dónde ves que el `std::string` pasado por parámetros se guarde en la variable miembro correspondiente? Haz esta corrección:

```
void Garito::setNombre(std::string nombre){
    if (nombre == "")
        throw std::string ("[setNombre]: No se ha introducido ningun texto"); 
    this->nombre = nombre;
}

void Garito::setDireccion(std::string direccion){
    if (direccion == "")
        throw std::string ("[setDireccion]: No se ha introducido ningun texto");
    this->direccion = direccion;
}
```