# Mostrar array de objetos con la clase vector

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo mostrar en pantalla los objetos creados en un array? Los objetos que quiero construir tienen dos parámetros definidos por defecto inicializados en el constructor por defecto. ¿Qué tendría que hacer?

Este es mi código:

```
    std::vector <Garito> garitos;
    garitos.emplace(garitos.end());
    /*
    std::cout << funciones::mostrarGarito(garitos); //Funcion que muestra los parametros de Garito a través de std::cout, pero no compila
   */


 return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Funcion que muestra los parametros de Garito a través de `std::cout`, pero no compila
>
> ```
> std::cout << funciones::mostrarGarito(garitos);
> ```

Si la función `mostrarGarito` es la misma que [defines en otra de tus preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/175048/2742):

```
void funciones::mostrarGarito(const Garito& g){
   std::cout <<"Nombre del Garito: "<<g.getNombre()<<std::endl; 
   std::cout <<"Direccion del Garito: "<<g.getDireccion()<<std::endl;
}
```

Es normal que no compile. Dejando de lado que el tipo definido como parámetro es diferente, la función está devolviendo nada (`void`) y le estás pasando nada para imprimir, el flujo de salida de datos (`std::cout`) no sabe cómo interpretar esa nada y el compilador se niega (correctamente) a compilarlo.

---

Para pasar `std::vector`es a los flujos de salida de datos deberás crear una función que los acepte, lo que se suele aconsejar es cobrecargar el operador de inyección de datos (`<<`):

```
template<typename T>
std::ofstream &operator <<(std::ofstream &o, const std::vector<T> &v)
{
    for (const auto &d : v)
        std::cout << d << '\n';
    return o;
}
```

El código anterior te permitirá mostrar datos de un vector siempre y cuando el dato contenido en el vector disponga del operador de inyección en flujo de datos, en tu caso `Garito` no dispone del mismo:

```
std::vector<int> i{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<Garito> g{Garito{}, Garito{}, Garito{}};

std::cout << i; // Correcto
std::cout << g; // Incorrecto, no hay sobrecarga de << para Garito.
```

Pero eso se puede solucionar sobrecargando el operador correspondiente también para Garito:

```
std::ofstream &operator <<(std::ofstream &o, const Garito &g)
{
    return (o << g.getNombre() << ' ' << getDireccion() << '\n');
}
```

Esto te permitirá hacer lo que buscabas:

```
std::vector <Garito> garitos;
garitos.emplace(garitos.end());
std::cout << garitos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para futuras preguntas, piensa que la declaración de la función `mostrarGarito` puede ser bastante importante... procura crear preguntas con toda la información necesaria.

Entiendo que la función `mostrarGarito` tiene la siguiente declaración (o una equivalente):

```
namespace funciones
{
  void mostrarGarito(Garito const&);
}
```

Pues bien, tu tienes un vector de garitos y una función que únicamente admite un objeto de tipo `Garito` ... la solución es usar un bucle:

```
for(Garito const& garito : garitos)
{
  funciones::mostrarGarito(garito);
}
```

Si no puedes / no te dejan compilar con el estándar C++11 y tienes que recurrir al ya arcaico C++98 puedes, por legibilidad, usar índices:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<garitos.size(); i++)
{
  funciones::mostrarGarito(garitos[i]);
}
```